# SQL UPDATE query with JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, prestashop

I already search and real all previous questions & answers about it but i just can't find the good way to do what i want, so maybe my problem can also help other people, let see.

I'm trying to use this SQL query :

```
UPDATE L

   SET L.description = REPLACE(L.description, '196,99', '197') 

  FROM ps_product_lang AS L 
  JOIN ps_product AS P 
    ON L.id_product = P.id_product



 WHERE P.id_category_default = 23
```

to replace a string in *ps_product_lang* table, column *description*

The WHERE clause have to match an ID from *ps_product* table (column *id_category_default*)

What is wrong here?

Comment: Take another look at UPDATE syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE ps_product_lang AS L 

  JOIN ps_product AS P 
    ON L.id_product = P.id_product

   SET L.description = REPLACE(L.description, '196,99', '197') 

 WHERE P.id_category_default = 23
```

Comment: so close :)  This works great ! thank you @Strawberry